# Delete a column in a data frame within a list

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I made a list out of my dataframe, based on the factor levels in column A. In the list I would like to remove that column. My head is saying lapply, but not anything else :P

```
$A
ID Test
A   1
A   1

$B
 ID Test
 B   1
 B   3
 B   5
```

Into this

```
$A
Test
 1
 1

$B
Test
 1
 3
 5
```

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Assuming your list is called `myList`, something like this should work:

```
lapply(myList, function(x) { x["ID"] <- NULL; x })
```

#### Update

For a more general solution, you can also use something like this:

```
# Sample data
myList <- list(A = data.frame(ID = c("A", "A"), 
                              Test = c(1, 1), 
                              Value = 1:2), 
               B = data.frame(ID = c("B", "B", "B"), 
                              Test = c(1, 3, 5), 
                              Value = 1:3))
# Keep just the "ID" and "Value" columns
lapply(myList, function(x) x[(names(x) %in% c("ID", "Value"))])
# Drop the "ID" and "Value" columns
lapply(myList, function(x) x[!(names(x) %in% c("ID", "Value"))])
```

Comment: thank you :) I think I'm beginning to see how to apply functions within lapply.. :)

Comment: @EndreGrünerOfstad, no problem. See my updated answer for another option you can use.

Comment: @mrwab Thanks! Btw, do you know how to merge two lists with the same element structure? E.g. one goes from two lists where each element level contains one vector each to one list where each element level contains two vectors. Perhaps it should be a question all by itself..

Comment: The last column in each data frame does not have a column name. How can I use lapply to drop that last column without using the col. names?

Comment: @SoilSciGuy, use something like `x[length(x)] <- NULL` instead?

Comment: @AHandcartAndMohair thanks for the great answer ! What is the significance of the semi-colon in the function? I don't quite understand what that means.

Comment: @vagabond, just to allow me to write two statements in the same line. If you didn't have the `; x` nothing would actually get returned....

Answer (score 14):

If you are `tidyverse` user there is an alternative solution, which utilizes `map` function from `purrr` package.

```
# Create same sample data as above
myList <- list(A = data.frame(ID = c("A", "A"), 
                              Test = c(1, 1), 
                              Value = 1:2), 
               B = data.frame(ID = c("B", "B", "B"), 
                              Test = c(1, 3, 5), 
                              Value = 1:3))
# Remove column by name in each element of the list
map(myList, ~ (.x %>% select(-ID)))
```

Answer (score 8):

We can efficiently use the bracket function `"["` here.

#### Example

```
L <- replicate(3, iris[1:3, 1:4], simplify=FALSE)  # example list
```

**Delete columns by numbers**

```
lapply(L, "[", -c(2, 3))
```

**Delete columns by names**

```
lapply(L, "[", -grep(c("Sepal.Width|Petal.Length"), names(L[[1]])))
```

**Result**

```
# [[1]]
#   Sepal.Length Petal.Width
# 1          5.1         0.2
# 2          4.9         0.2
# 3          4.7         0.2
# 
# [[2]]
#   Sepal.Length Petal.Width
# 1          5.1         0.2
# 2          4.9         0.2
# 3          4.7         0.2
```

Answer (score 3):

If you had a data frame that didn't contain the `ID` column, you could use `map_if` to remove it only where it exists.

```
myList <- list(A = data.frame(ID = c("A", "A"), 
                          Test = c(1, 1), 
                          Value = 1:2), 
           B = data.frame(ID = c("B", "B", "B"), 
                          Test = c(1, 3, 5), 
                          Value = 1:3),
           C = data.frame(Test = c(1, 3, 5), 
                          Value = 1:3))
map_if(myList, ~ "ID" %in% names(.x), ~ .x %>% select(-ID), .depth = 2)
```